# How to get the browsing history in android for a particular time period

Tags: android, android-browser

I would like to develop an android app for accessing the history of the browser with in a certain time interval by using AlaramManager, but when I access the history infomation, i'm getting the new information along with the previous history. Is there any way to to get the history of last few(5 or 10) minutes

Below is the code for accesing the browsing history

```
        String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL , Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE};
        Uri uriCustom = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
        String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
        Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uriCustom, proj, sel, null, null);
        //this.startManagingCursor(mCur);
        mCur.moveToFirst();

        String title = "";
        String url = "";
        String date_time="";
        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
                url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
                date_time=mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
                // Do something with title and url
                System.out.println("Title="+title+"---"+url);
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `" AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + "BETWEEN ? AND ?"` to your `sel` variable and pass `new String[]{startdate, enddate}` in `selectionArgs` of query method.
Modify the `startdate` and `enddate` as per your requirements. This method will return the data between to specific time period. We are just making sql query to get data between two particular time period. Ex :

```
String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0 " +" AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + "BETWEEN ? AND ?"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uriCustom, proj, sel, new String[]{startdate, enddate}, null);
```

Comment: [Most things related to Bookmarks-Browser were removed in API Level 23 (Android 6.0+)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)